# Google Analytics tracking custom data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have android game and i want to get stats how many times one user plays (per device).

I know that i need to use customvar but how this stats will be visualized in panel ga ?

What is the best approach to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

When testing, make a temporary Google Analytics project, and use that key to track your event and custom variables. The you'll be able to see if they are being tracked the way you want or not.